# DialogFlow ES play singular vs. plural

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm newish to DF and integrating it with Cisco IVR, so trying not to use webhooks if possible. I want caller to say something like "buy a ticket from boston to miami" vs. "buy 3 coach tickets" and I'm using required parameters for qty, fromcity, tocity, seat_class.

In the Response I'd like to play it back as 'looking up $qty (ticket|tickets) from $fromcity to $tocity in $seat_class class.

Is there a way to do the singular vs. plural of the word 'ticket' by creating a custom entity or something?

I tried to create an entity numTickets to capture 'a ticket' vs. '@sys.number-integer tickets' but can't figure out what to put into the entity's 'reference value' field to get the actual number of tickets to be returned. I tried returning @sys.number-integer but that's literally what I got back, rather than the value of that.

Thanks